# Angular material select get reset

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, material-design, angular-material

I'm facing another problem with Angular Material.

Now I have a form, with two select. The problem is when I select one value in any of this two select, the other one get reseted and loose his value.

is this a bug? or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
<form name="addTarjeta">
  <div ng-controller="MedioPagoController">
      <md-input-container class="md-icon md-block">
          <label>Tipo de tarjeta</label>
          <md-icon class="material-icons">&#xE252;</md-icon>
          <md-select ng-model="_tarjeta.medioPago" md-on-open="listaMedioPago()"
                     required name="medio">                                            
              <md-option value="{{medio}}" 
                         ng-repeat="medio in medioPagos track by medio.idMedioPago">{{medio.nombrePago}}</md-option>                                            
          </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="EntidadBancariaController">
      <md-input-container class="md-icon md-block">
          <label>Entidad bancaria</label>
          <md-icon class="material-icons">&#xE84F;</md-icon>
          <md-select ng-model="_tarjeta.medioPago" md-on-open="listaEntidadBancaria()"
                     required name="entidad">                                            
              <md-option value="{{entidad}}" 
                         ng-repeat="entidad in entidadBancarias">{{entidad.nombreEntidad}}</md-option>                                            
          </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
   </div>  
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried binding the selects to different `ng-model`. Now both selects are binding to `_tarjeta.medioPago`. You use different controllers, so it should work... but could you try it? just to discard.

Comment: You know, i'm feeling very, very bad, i'm ashamed for not seeing it before, i was 3 hours thinking what's the problem. i'm so sorry. and thank you form helping me

Comment: You're welcome, and no worries at all :). I've posted the comment as an answer, just in case you want to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I post in a comment:

You are binding both selects to the same `ng-model="_tarjeta.medioPago"`, so this is the expected behaviour.

I think it's probably just a typo in your code. Could you check it?
Change the `ng-model` of (probably) your second select to another variable of the controller and the problem should disapear.

Hope it helps